# cakephp controller not found error on production server

Tags: php, cakephp, path, controller

I have  a cakephp project under folder FC such that on ubuntu, it's path is `/var/www/FC/app/...`
Upon uploading to ec2 and making all configuration changes, the base path, ie. index.php is correctly opening but any other link on index.php is giving an error:

> Error: FCController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class FCController below in file: app/Controller/FCController.php

```
class FCController extends AppController {

}
```

Upon creating this file, it asks to put method locations into the class FCcontroller, and on putting an empty method in the class, the display goes blue like an empty page.
Since I haven't written this code I have no clue where the data which should be here is written...what should I Do?

Comment: can you please update controller code with the method you wrote....and for that blue screen look into views folder you will see layout.ctp file...that is the file which is main template file.

Comment: There's no method in FCcontroller, in fact there is no FCcontroller in my code. I just made an empty method as the error was showing me to do to check what happens...I think default path to controller is set incorrectly, how do I change path to controller, where is it given in configuration?

Comment: you can see it at Config folder...and inside that folder you will see `route.php` file...

Comment: Ok, so in routes.php, these are the two routes shown:

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'locations', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

So locations is my main controller which goes to action index. Is the second command incorrect? Because pages is the default example given by cake, I checked. What happens on using the second command?

Comment: Sounds like just an issue with the paths needing altered in the webroot/index

Comment: here's contents for my index.php:
if (!defined('DS')) {
 define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
 define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
 define('APP_DIR', basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
}

define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', DS . 'var' . DS . 'www' . DS . 'FC' . DS . 'lib');

As you can see the path for app is not defined, only cake_core is defined...do i need to add/alter  anything? What would it be?  Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i sorted the issue out. It was because in my code, the previous user had made a controller file Locationscontroller.php and specified urls like this:

```
<form id ="0" action="/FC/locations/confirm_final">
```

This was for localhost in my local machine where the base folder was htdocs I had to type localhost/FC/ to access index.php. 
So naturally Since on EC2 I had made FC itself my base folder, it was trying to access another FC inside it which didn't exist. The /XXX/locations/  means it searches for "XXX" controller and then locations inside it. Since my controller was Locations, it kept giving an error.

As soon as I changed it to this:

```
<form id ="0" action="/locations/confirm_final">
```

It pointed to the right controller which was locations.
It was all because I didn't check which controller was called by which View!
I'm an idiot, that'll be all :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter these three lines in your `app\webroot\index.php`:

```
// The full path to the directory which holds "app", WITHOUT a trailing DS.
define('ROOT', '/var/www/FC');

// The actual directory name for the "app".
define('APP_DIR', 'app');

// The absolute path to the "cake" directory, WITHOUT a trailing DS.
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
```

to point to their respective locations.

(the last of the three is commented by default, so you'll need to uncomment it.

Comment: Hi dave, 
Thanks for the reply! So if the path to my cake folder is this:
/var/www/FC/app/webroot  

What do I write in the first two lines?
I tried giving the path but it didnt work, can you please give me specific command acc to the path i gave above? Thanks so much!

Comment: Edited answer with what I think would be your paths.E

Comment: Hi! I did the alteration but the error persists :( Could it be an issue with the 3 htaccess files?
I have not given rewrite base command etc. and my cakephp lies inside www in FC folder so do I need to rewrite base as FC?

PS-there's another index.php in base FC folder, do I need to change the cake_core config there as well? it shows the old default one now..
PS2-could it be something about the allowoverride all? The default file has 4 allow overrides and the first 2 i've set to all, last 2 are still set to none...

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the `.htaccess` files, but you will have to change your 'CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH' to wherever your CakePHP is.

Comment: I've including the cake_core path in both index.php files in FC and webroot..it keeps giving FCController not found, create it error...Do you think I need to compulsorily have an FCController.php file?

Comment: You should not be changing any file(s) other than the `webroot/index.php`.  (and possibly `test.php`, but that's later)

Comment: So what could the problem be, I've changed index.php as required but it's not taking :( Could you please give me any alternatives?

Comment: Try the normal debugging path.  Start from scratch on an empty project, see if you can get it to work, then add from there.