# CakePHP missing controller on EC2

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Cake 2.3.8 app that works fine on localhost and I uploaded it to an Ubuntu 12.04 EC2 instance, but on the index/home file I'm getting a "Missing Controller" error.

The CSS, header and footer load fine on the home/index page, but it can't seem to find the controller. Every single other page/controller of my app won't even load, I get a 404 error.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547869/cakephp-controller-not-found-error-on-production-server) but my issue still persists.

What else should I look for that would cause it to not find the controller and not even load any other pages?

**Update**

I moved my contents to /var/www so it would be accessed through my-ec2-instance.com. When I go to my-ec2-instance.com/index.php the page displays (which is PagesController/home.ctp). However, anything else gives a 404 error. Modrewrite is also enabled

I can also access my actions when I reference index.php, although it displays in mobile format for whatever reason (I have a responsive template). Ex: www.my-ec2-instance.com/index.php/users/login works, although it's in a mobile format

```
www.my-ec2-instance.com/index.php  //works

www.my-ec2-instance.com/index.php/users/login  //works, but mobile format

www.my-ec2-instance.com/users/login  //404 error
```

Comment: can you add the exact error message here?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla It says "Missing Controller Error: Project1Controller could not be found.". This is on the index page, which would be the PagesController.

Comment: what is the url you are using?

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla I'm accessing exactly as if I would on localhost. my-ec2-url.com/Project1

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla My app is located in /var/www/Project1 not /var/www. When I visit that it just shows the apache "It Works" message.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42231/discussion-between-guillemo-mansilla-and-user1443519)

Answer (score 1):

Please connect your instance via putty then press

```
sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Check the given below line and remove the # tag

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

After that you can replace:

```
AllowOverride None
```

with

```
AllowOverride All
```

*Note: AllowOverride None `->` AllowOverride All.*

From <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then press <kbd>Y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (you can use this command according to your OS)

After that you can execute the command in putty

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Then check your `.htaccess` file (please make sure your `.htaccess` should be correct) for cakePHP `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with your `.htaccess` file which is what would properly rewrite short URLs & handling controller routing.

Comment: Which .htaccess specifically? I looked through and there appear to be mulptiple (/.htaccess , /app/.htaccess , /app/webroot/.htaccess). My regex skills are lacking, so I'm not quite sure what I'd be looking for anyway. Thanks for the suggestion though!